# RestSharp: Converting results

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I get the following JSON that I am trying to convert to a business object using RestSharp

```
  {
  "valid":true,
  "data":[
    {
       "dealerId":"4373",
       "branchId":"4373",
    }
  ]
  }
```

I wish to convert to:

```
public class Dealer
{
    public string dealerId ;
    public string branchId;
   }
```

But this fails, though the JSON is fine:

```
        var client = new RestClient("http://www.????.com.au");
        var request = new RestRequest(string.Format("service/autocomplete/dealer/{0}/{1}.json", suburb.PostCode, suburb.City.Trim().Replace(" ", "%20")), Method.GET);
        var response2 = client.Execute<Dealer>(request);
        return response2.Data;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your business object doesn't match the response JSON you are getting back. If you want your response to serialize, your C# object would look something like

```
public class DealerResponse
{
    public bool valid { get;set; }
    List<Dealer> data { get;set; }
}

public class Dealer
{
    public string dealerId;         
    public string branchId;   
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but even though you are only interested in the information in 'data', your response C# objects still need to represent the whole JSON response to serialize correctly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent. I knew there must be a simple way to do it. Works like a charm. Vote++